# Vertical gaps between inline-block elements for big amounts of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently doing the [JS/jQuery Project](http://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/javascript-and-jquery) for The Odin Project and i think my solution is performing really well.

The problem i have with it tho, is that for bigger amounts of elements (in JSFiddle it starts to break around 40-45 elements per line, in my Chrome Browser around 50-52), there will be a vertical gap between the elements of two adjacent rows. I initially set `vertical-align: top` to remove the gaps, which works up to the mentioned 40-50 elements per row.

[Here is the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kjme2jub/)

If you raise the amount of elements per row in the JS file (set it to 50 or higher), you will see what i mean.

This is not the behavior i am looking for. I want a connected grid with no gaps between the cells on either side. Any idea what breaks the `vertical-align: top`?

**Edit**: I think it has to do with the percentage-width/height, as it also breaks on numbers below 40, if the result of the division is a "difficult fraction".

Comment: If you will use `float` instead of `inline-block`, problem will be fixed.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Can you explain, why this fixes the problem, or is it some weird inline-block specific thing?

Comment: This question breaks two rules of SO so I don't know why it's upvoted so much when better questions get downvoted: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Also Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code

Comment: If you do not want to use float - the main cause of your problem is that when you get over 40 blocks, the amount of blocks on a line mean that the blocks are now smaller than the line height causing the extra space.  If you want to carry on using display:inline-block instead of floating, just set the line height for the container to zero

Comment: @Pete I see where you are coming from, but i personally dislike questions that bombard me with a wall of code. I think JSFiddle is a great tool to give other people on SO a chance to easily try it out and change things, to see if their solution to the problem works, before posting a answer. If the links were taken down regularly i would post the code, but they are stable, so why not leave it where it can easily be executed?

Comment: @Pete If you post that as an answer i will accept it. Just the explanation i needed.

Comment: It's the rules of the site Luca.  This is a resource site so it is meant to be useful for future visitors.  If your link to jsfiddle goes dead, then this question has no use to anyone in future.  Also, if you dislike the wall of code, then just make a code snippet and hide it.  Just because you don't like something doesn't mean you can break the rules - you wouldn't break the law just because you didn't like something?

Comment: This is basically what you are doing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it, but instead of your site, you are just pasting a link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline boxes inherit inheritable properties from their block parent box. therefore your grids are taking `line-height` of `.container`. When  `.container` is overflowed `vertical-align: top;` stops working, so it's better to use `line-height:0;` to parent element (`.container`).

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    createGrid(48);
    $(".cell").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    });
    $(".cell").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    });
});

function createGrid(n) {
    var container = $(".container");
    container.empty();

    var sizeP = 100 / n;

    var cell = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'cell',
        style: 'width: ' + sizeP + '%; height: ' + sizeP + '%;'
    });

    for(i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
        container.append(cell.clone());
    }
}
```

```css
.container {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    line-height:0;
}

.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```